# Cant get my foor loop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

Why isn't this working?

```js
var i = 0;
for (i < 1) {
  if ($(".button[name=commit]").val() == "remove"){
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

I get this error message saying: `unexpcted token ) at line 2`.

Comment: Learn how `for` loops are supposed to work.

Comment: This code makes no sense. You're checking the same button every time through the loop. If the condition isn't true, the loop will continue forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using `while` loop

```
var i = 0;
while (i < 1) {
  if ($(".button[name=commit]").val() == "remove"){
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

Here you go with a solution using `for` loop

```
for (var i=0; i<1;) {
  if ($(".button[name=commit]").val() == "remove"){
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The second loop will just run once, regardless of what the `if` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!$(".button[name=commit]").val() == "remove");
```

it was not working since for() needs 3 commands: Initialization, guard and last action: `for(init;guard;action)`